# Selling or sold?

Tags: past-participles, present-participles

> **Selling** for $40, the gadget will give you great value.
>
> **Selling** for $40, the gadget may seem expensive at first sight.

In the context of the sentences, there is no particular item that has been sold. 
Could **sold** be used in place of **selling**?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: There is a particular item, the gadget. Do you mean that it has not been sold *yet*? That the transaction is not completed?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Right. If the sentence occurs in an advertisement and it means "available at a particular price," could "sold" be used in place of "selling"?

Comment: Can a cookbook say *This dish is **served** with rice* if the meal hasn't even been prepared yet?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't really know. And I am not sure if the context is the same as the OP.

Comment: The item being sold is one of many exactly like it.  Items exactly like this one are sold for $40.  That is, whenever a purchase occurs involving one of them, the selling price is $40.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because "sell" is an ergative verb.

We can say "I sell the gadget for £40", and "The gadget sells for £40". This type of verb in which a secondary meaning of "sell" is "be sold" is called an ergative verb.

So you can say "Sold for £40..." (using the normal passive) or "Selling for £40" (using the ergative)

Comment: But in the context of the sentences, there is no particular item that has been sold. Cold **sold** still be used?

Comment: That demerit wasn't from me, by the way.

Comment: I would say that the "gadget" is the particular item.  The past participle indicates the price that it "is sold" for (whether or not it "has sold" at that price)

Comment: In common usage, "sold for" would typically be applied to something for which there is more than a single unit of the item for sale.  It refers to the usual selling price of the item.  It isn't typically used when referring to a one-off item offered for sale.