# The books have sold vs. The books have been sold

Tags: phrase-usage

Do both "The books have sold" and "The books have been sold" natural and appropriate in English?

"The books have sold" sounds as if the book can sell themselves. Can they?

> List of best-selling books - Wikipediaen.wikipedia.org › wiki › List_of_best-selling_books
> **The books have sold** more than 150 million copies and have spawned two film adaptations, with a third one slated for release next year." (4 February 2018)

Comment: The first means that the books are a success. The second means there was a limited supply of the books, which have all been sold.

Comment: You can say that a commodity 'sells well' when a lot of people want to buy it. This is a shorter way of saying "More than 150m copies of the books have been sold".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selling or sold?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175835/selling-or-sold)

Comment: to sell = **to be bought** in the way or quantities that are mentioned; **to be sold** at the price mentioned e.g How much does the phone sell for?